# c# - How to set Image source of an Image from FTP

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, ftp-client

So I have this code that gets the image from my FTP server, then I want set its source from ftp server. What I get is this `cannot convert 'System.IO.Stream' to 'System.Func<System.IO.Stream>'`  from this line `imgs.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(img);`

I am using xamarin.Forms on Android btw.

```
private void loadImage(string source)
        {
            try
            {
                string ftpfullpath = source;
                FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);
                ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword);

                ftp.KeepAlive = true;
                ftp.UseBinary = true;
                ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

                using (var request = ftp.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (var img = request.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        imgs.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(img);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: I havent tried such thing. But as far as I see, it complains about the fact thst you are trying to supply the stream itself. But it is most likelly asinchronously fetched. Thus you need to supply a fuction that will return the stream when called. Like this: ImageSource.FromStream(() =>img); - beware, this is just the idea, might worth refactoring.

Comment: thanks I tried it but it doesnt work, what I also try is  imgs.Source = ImageSource.FromUri(ftp.GetResponse().URi....

Comment: Wrap all the fetch stuff inside a function that returns the stream.